# Cant access constant POLLIN from select module with python 2.7 or 3.3 on windows

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have a script that does this. (Note that this isn't the actual script but its the minimalistic version that contains the error for simplicity)

```
import select
rmask = select.POLLIN|select.POLLERR|select.POLLHUP <--- ERROR
smask = select.POLLOUT|select.POLLIN|select.POLLERR|select.POLLHUP <--- ERROR
class PollSocket(SelectSocket):
def __init__(self, timer):
    super().__init__(timer)
    self.pollobj = select.poll()
    self.pollobj.register(self.sock, smask)

def poll(self):
    flags = []
    if self.sending:
        self.pollobj.register(self.sock, smask)
        self.sending = False
    else:
        self.pollobj.register(self.sock, rmask)
    try:
        poll = self.pollobj.poll(self.timer.get_timeout())
    except select.error as e:
        print(str(e))
        poll = []
    if poll:
        poll = poll[0][1]
        if poll&select.POLLERR: flags.append('SOCKET_ERR') <--- ERROR
        if poll&select.POLLHUP: flags.append('SOCKET_HUP') <--- ERROR
        if poll&select.POLLIN:  flags.append('SOCKET_RECV') <--- ERROR
        if poll&select.POLLOUT: flags.append('SOCKET_SEND') <--- ERROR
    return flags

def reset(self):
    self.pollobj.unregister(self.sock)
    self.sock.close()
    self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.sock.setblocking(0)
    self.pollobj.register(self.sock)
```

And I get this error.

rmask = select.POLLIN|select.POLLERR|select.POLLHUP

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'POLLIN'

I have tried just importing all from select by doing from select import * but that also fails.

I want to know how I can access the constants from select using a Windows system.

Here is a link to the select lib page for your convenience if you need it.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html

Look at section 16.1.2

Comment: Windows doesn't support the `poll()` system call, so this is never going to work unless you rewrite your code to use a different I/O primitive instead such as `select()`.